# Parallelization on Databricks using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, parallel-processing, databricks

I am working on doing parallelization run of on a same child notebook on a parent notebook.
I have a frame work that I use the concurrent.futures modules in Python to enable the parallelization.

I have installed all the libraries at the beginning of the parent notebook in R, (the child notebook is partially in R) but while I check the run of the child notebook, some Cmd in the middle just got cancelled automatically but if I run the notebooks not parallely, this won’t happen, just wondering do you know something similar or related that what are some causes of this issue? And do you have any other advises on doing parallelization using Python in databricks?

Thank you very much!